# Passing data from Unmanaged code to managed code

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, interop, native-code

I have a three layered application:

1. A managed c# layer.
2. A managed c++/cli layer.
3. A unmanaged c++ layer.

The second layer is used as a layer of communication between c# and native c++.

```
public class ManagedResult
{
  public float[] firstArray;
  public float[] secondArray;
}
```

and the unmanaged class

```
 class UnmanagedResult
    {
      public:
         float* firstArray, secondArray;
         int arrayLength;
         UnmanagedResult(){};
         ~UnmanagedResult(){};
    }
```

I have in the second layer the following method of a class wich outputs a managed object:

```
 ManagedResult^ CLIContext::GetResults(){

   ManagedResult^ primitiveResult = gcnew ManagedResult();

   pin_ptr<int> pFirst = &(primitiveResult->firstArray[0]);
   pin_ptr<float> pSecond = &(primitiveResult->secondArray[0]);
   UnmanagedResult result =UnmanagedResult();
   result.firstArray = pFirst;
   result.secondArray = pSecond;

   _context->GetResults(result);

   return primitiveResult;

 }
```

Here the _context is an object of unmanaged class type which manipulates an object of type UnmanagedResult and affects its content.

This solution works fine. But I want to be able to pass by reference the object and with a third party API to alloc and populate the two members `firstArray` and `secondArray`.
How can I transfer data then from unmanaged result back to primitiveResult?

Comment: For *unmanaged to managed*, you need a separate variable to hold the item count - can you provide that? Also, you'll have to *copy* the array contents, because you can't put a managed array on top of existing data, unfortunately. Is this ok for you?

Comment: Yes I can provide the number of items in. I am interested how can I copy the array contents from one layer to another the fastest way possible.

Comment: Well, if you want it as fast as possible then don't copy.  You probably want to return IntPtr from whatever ref class wrapper that wraps that 3rd party api and cast to (float*) again in this one.

Answer (score 1):

As an unmanaged array is just a pointer to its first item, you need to know the item count.

If you want a managed array, you'll have to create one and copy the data there. You won't be able to create a managed array that points to existing unmanaged memory.

Use [`System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a53bd6cz.aspx) for that:

```
UnmanagedResult unmanagedResult = GetTheUnmanagedResultSomehow();
ManagedResult^ managedResult = gcnew ManagedResult();

managedResult->firstArray = gcnew array<float>(unmanagedResult.arrayLength);
Marshal::Copy(IntPtr(unmanagedResult.firstArray), managedResult->firstArray, 0, managedResult->firstArray->Length); 

// Do the same for secondArray
```